# Custom app.config section fails to cast to NameValueCollection

Tags: c#, web-config, app-config

[This tutorial](http://blog.danskingdom.com/adding-and-accessing-custom-sections-in-your-c-app-config/) makes what I'm trying to do look dead easy. All I want to do is read a custom attribute out of my `web.config`. Here's the relevant part:

```
<configSections>
    <section name="Authentication.WSFedShell" type="System.Configuration.DictionarySectionHandler, System, Version=1.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
</configSections>

<Authentication.WSFedShell>
    <add key="Authentication.PrincipalType" value="ClientCertificate" />
</Authentication.WSFedShell>
```

In the immediate window I can execute:

`System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection("Authentication.WSFedShell")`

which returns the string

`["Authentication.PrincipalType"]: "ClientCertificate"`

However, when I try to cast it (with `as NameValueCollection`), as [this tutorial](http://blog.danskingdom.com/adding-and-accessing-custom-sections-in-your-c-app-config/) says to do, I get `null` returned and my code blows up. There's gotta be a cleaner way to get the value "ClientCertificate" than manually parsing the string result.

**How do I read "ClientCertificate" from `app.config`?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why can't you use [`AppSetting`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/610xe886.aspx) like

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="Authentication.PrincipalType" value="ClientCertificate"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>

   System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Authentication.PrincipalType"]
```

Most probably the issue with your section is the `Type` attribute.  But anyways, you need to cast the result of `GetSection()` to your type defined for section like

```
System.Configuration.DictionarySectionHandler config = (System.Configuration.DictionarySectionHandler)System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection("Authentication.WSFedShell");
```

Comment: The production environment I'm deploying to has a section requirement. I had this working with the simpler-to-use `appSetting`. I'm refactoring it to utilize sections